# How to get specific value from data frame according other variable in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have an "issue" variable that will change according to user input, for example I choose Unbonded.
And I make "currentdata" variable to get data from database like this.

```
issue <- "Unbonded"

currentdata <- dbGetQuery(con,paste0("SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
                                                Unbonded,
                                                Clogged,
                                                Dirty,
                                                Leaking,
                                                Others
                                                FROM Table_Analytic
                                                ORDER BY Table_Analytic.ID DESC;"))

currentissue <- currentdata$ ????
```

How can I get only the values ​​that match with the issue to put into the "currentissue" variable

Thankyou

Comment: What's the structure of `currentdata`?  See the behavior of `%in%`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
currentissue <- currentdata[[issue]]
```